# AES Проблема при расшифровке, ошибка на последнем блоке

Tags: aes

Приветствую всех! Проблема незначительная, но она имеет место быть.
Шифрование работает на ура, расшифровка- почти, а именно расшифровывает, но выдает на последнем блоке ошибку "заполнение неверно и не может быть удалено".

Стектрейс таков:

> Заполнение неверно и не может быть удалено.
>   описание ошибки:
>      в System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
>      в System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
>      в System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
>      в System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>      в System.IO.Stream.Close()
>      в System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
>      в MyEncryptor.Crypto.Decrypt_AES_File(String input, String output, String passPhrase, String saltValue, String hashString, Int32 Iterations, String initVector, Int32 keySize) в e:\IT\GITreps\MyExamples\MVCexample\MyEncryptor\Crypto.cs:строка 207
>      в MyEncryptor.MainPresenter`1.DecFile_AES_RSA(Int32 fileIndex) в e:\IT\GITreps\MyExamples\MVCexample\MyEncryptor\MainPresenter.cs:строка 331
>      в MyEncryptor.MainPresenter`1._view_FileOpenClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) в e:\IT\GITreps\MyExamples\MVCexample\MyEncryptor\MainPresenter.cs:строка 177

Шифрование:

```
public bool Encrypt_AES_File(string input, string output, string passPhrase, string saltValue, string hashString, int Iterations,
                                                                                                    string initVect, int keySize)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVect);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashString, Iterations);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
        RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        byte[] progs = File.ReadAllBytes(input);
        CurrentMaxProg = progs.Length;
        byte[] buf = new byte[128];
        int BytesRead = 0;

        using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create))
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open))
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    if (_cancelled)
                    {
                        CurrentProg = 0;
                        CurrentMaxProg = 0;
                        return false;
                    }
                    BytesRead = fsIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    CurrentProg += BytesRead;
                    if (BytesRead == 0) break;
                    cryptoStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    CurrentProgressChanged(CurrentProg);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                while (BytesRead != 0);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                CurrentProg = 0;
                CurrentMaxProg = 0;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return false; }
        }
    }
```

Расшифровка:

```
public bool Decrypt_AES_File(string input, string output, string passPhrase, string saltValue, string hashString, int Iterations,
                                                                                                    string initVector, int keySize)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashString, Iterations);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
        RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        byte[] progs = File.ReadAllBytes(input);
        CurrentMaxProg = progs.Length;
        byte[] buf = new byte[128];
        int BytesRead = 0;

        using (FileStream fsDecrypt = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
        using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOut, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    if (_cancelled)
                    {
                        CurrentProg = 0;
                        CurrentMaxProg = 0;
                        return false;
                    }
                    BytesRead = fsDecrypt.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    CurrentProg += BytesRead;
                    if (BytesRead == 0) break;
                    cryptoStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    CurrentProgressChanged(CurrentProg);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                while (BytesRead != 0);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                CurrentProg = 0;
                CurrentMaxProg = 0;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return false; }
        }
    }
```

Вызов корректен. Ошибка возникает на строке

```
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
```

Почему думаю, что расшифровывается корректно? Испытывал на .mp3. Шифрует правильно, т.к. если после шифрования изменить расширение файла вручную или тупо с расширением .crypt закинуть в проигрыватель, то он не воспроизводится. Если после расшифровки закинуть полученный файл в проигрыватель, воспроизводиться без пробелов, от начала и до конца. Кто знает как исправить?

Comment: Что кроме зашифрованных данных в файл пишете?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что ничего. Мне думается, что проблема все-таки исходит вот из этой строки    byte[] buf = new byte[128];

Comment: Ничего это хорошо... А какой размер файла (на котором при расшифровке ошибка) получается в байтах?

Comment: В принципе на любом ошибку выдавал. Самый маленький файл был 5 394 432 байт

Comment: Ага, выровнен на 16. Да, думаю вы правильно про buf думаете: читаете 128 байт, шифруете, и пишете тоже 128 байт. Последний блок в 1 байт во что превратится в итоге?

Comment: Не очень силен в этом, но думаю, шифруется 1 байт данных и еще 127 байт мусора, или 127 нулевых байт, и по этой причине при расшифровке и выскакивает ошибка.

Comment: Вот я тоже так думаю. Я не знаю как именно .NET реализовывает дополнение неполного блока. Попробуйте буфер 16 байт сделать...

Comment: Попробую, но уже завтра. Сам думал попробовать переделать строку `cryptoStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);` на конструкцию типа `byte[] encrypted = bytesRead == buf.Length? cryptoStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length) :  cryptoStream.Write(buf, 0, 1);` Но это так, навскидку.

Comment: заменил объявление буфера на `byte[] buf = new byte[16];` и все заработало без ошибок. Но я так и не понял, откуда берется 1 байт, ведь 5 394 432 байт делить на 128, 64 и т.д. байт  дает нам целое число.

Comment: 1 байт был для примера. Надо смотреть детали реализации шифрования в .NET чтобы понять что там было на самом деле...